# Run node.js from the browser on client side

Tags: javascript, node.js

I need to run node.js from the browser (on client side).
Certainly the Node.js is already installed on the client

For a simple example. Html-page contains only one button. If you click on this button must run node.js on the client side and execute node.js code:

```
//it is an ordinary browser js code
$("#btn").on("click", function () {
   //execute node.js code ON CLIENT SIDE
});
```

Comment: node is not on the client (browser). Are you meaning to run local nodejs code on the clients computer?

Comment: you can't access the local machine from the browser code

Comment: *"client side"* is considered to be the browser, node is the server. Browsers don't run server code

Answer (score 2):

That's not possible, even if `node.js` is installed on the client, you can't interact with it from the browser.

The only way is to start the node server and use `HTTP` to communicate with node.

Comment: Do you mean that on each client must be running the node server and the browser will be able to interact with it via HTTP?

Comment: @const No, if node is running on your client and you want to communicate with it, you can use HTTP. You can't touch other peoples `node` thats `hacking`!

Comment: Of course, in the previous comment I meant interaction between local node server (which on client side) and browser code.

Comment: This is actually not impossible, since Node.js servers can run on the client-side using WebContainers.

Answer (score -2):

Have a glance @ following points might lead you to clearance:

1. Node.js can't be over client side
2. It's basically a server that have to started @ one end before it could be used with client conjuction
3. However it could be restarted or make to run continuously using nodemon, forever but for first also it had to be started manually
4. you can't access the local machine from the browser code( @giannisf for #thanks)
5. Handling Node.js Remotely could be beneficial for you so google it

**Thanks & Cheeer**